# Is there some term that unifies "buying in", "rebuying" a player and or "average" and "addon" being purchased by a player?

Tags: terminology

To say that a player bought in to the game means a very specific thing and the same goes for rebuying and adding on or buying the average. Is there some term that could mean all of them? Like "entering" the game? "Buying in" the game could technically mean that but it also means a very specific thing and that could get confusing.

Comment: I'd say officially no, but just calling for "chips" is the closest I could think that could cover everything.

Comment: I would say "buy-in" covers at least the two first. E.g. "I busted out on the first hand, so I rebought" could also be phrased as "I busted out on the first hand, so I bought in again". You could also imagine someone saying "I'm on my third buy-in of the night". A rebuy is a particular kind of buy-in (it's specifically not the first), but I don't think there is anything about the word buy-in that in itself implies that it is the first, so I don't see how it could get confusing.

Answer (score -1):

You almost answered your own question when you wrote: "Buying in" the game could technically mean that but it also means a very specific thing and that could get confusing.

A good observation, different rules at different card rooms, apply to different terms for a buy-in. often there are rules for re-buys in a cash game most common being for a player whom has bought into a game and lost the original, buy in may buy in, for half a full buy in so of course there needs to be a term ( LIKE 'REBUY') that describes this situation in the rule book. Another term ADD-ON, applies to a player adding chips to a dwindling stack. So no there is no single Term that is used to describe all buy ins. It is a much more practical thing to be granular and precise with the terms. It as you implied avoides some confusion. Buy-ins, re-buys - add ons, in both cash games and tournaments are all different things.

Comment: The questions is explicitly seeking a single term that covers all of these together. This post does not answer the question at all buly merely presenting a number of different specific terms, all of which the question already mentions.